# Facebook API: (#100) No matching user found

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

I spent whole days to try to figure out this error, I also notice there are similar questions with the same message, but I'm totally not sure I find the answer in there, so if someone could point out or give any tip into my problem, I totally appreciate that.

I'm making the request to send a message from a Facebook page A to a user X (by userId) who makes a comment on a post of FB Page A, through a testing FB App name **MyApp**. I am trying this on Facebook Graph Explorer.

I got the user Id by fetch the list of comments in a post in the Facebook Page, but I totally could not send the message.

Here is the error

```
{
      "error": {
        "message": "(#100) No matching user found",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2018001,
        "fbtrace_id": "H3yMO0RWaDy"
      }
}
```

Here is the my track

1. MyApp has been setup webhook OK, because it is not published yet for the testing purpose (unapproved app), so I have to add the user X account into tester pool of MyApp (the message that I try to send is also this user X)
2. I logged into user X to make a comment on a post in the FB Page A
3. On Graph Explorer, I selected Application: **MyApp**, and get **Page Access Token of FB Page A**, I performed two following requests

3.1 `/{page_id}_{post_id}?fields=comments`
With this, I can get the list of existing comments in FB Page A, here is the output:

```
{
    "comments": {
        "data": [
                  {
                    "created_time": "...",
                    "from": {
                      "name": "User X",
                      "id": "123456789" // this is the user Id that I would take to send the message to
                    },
                    "message": "Sample comment from User X",
                    "id": "..." // {page_id}_{post_id}
                  }
                ],
                "paging": {
                   ....
                }
              },
              "id": "..." // {page_id}_{post_id
    }
}
```

3.2 `{page_id}/messages`: I am trying to send a message from FB Page A to user X with the user Id that I got from 3.1 step

```
recipient: {id: "123456789"} // there seems be a problem with this id that I got from step 3.1, FB cannot find the user id with this number
message: {text: "hello"}
```

I'm also acknowledged about the app/page scoped id for user.

I have already subscribed MyApp to the FB Page A with API `(/{page_id}/subscribed_apps)`

> Facebook API v2.10

I have no clue what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. Facebook Messenger Platform use paged scope user id, but what I were using is app scope id. They are different.

Here is official doc from Facebook about how to get the paged scope id

> The id must be an ID that was retrieved through the Messenger entry
>   points or through the Messenger webhooks (e.g., a person may discover
>   your business in Messenger and start a conversation from there.
>
> These IDs are page-scoped IDs (PSID). This means that the IDs are
>   unique for a given page.
>
> If you have an existing Facebook Login integration, user IDs are
>   app-scoped and will not work with the Messenger platform.

The solution is subscribing MyApp to the FB Page (what I've already done) to get the webhook to work, where I will get the page scope id from the message of user.

Furthermore, detail of how to setup the subscription found here

http://ukimiawz.github.io/facebook/2015/08/12/webhook-facebook-subscriptions/